# Using HTTP Authorization header in python

Tags: python, http, request

how can i make this request in python using requests library.

```
curl -H "Authorization: 563492ad6f91700001000001e4d5ce6a4c3986a01" "http://api.pexels.com/v1/search?query=people"
```

I tried using this code , but it not working for some reason.

```
from requests.auth import HTTPBasicAuth
requests.get('http://api.pexels.com/v1/search?query=sea&per_page=15&page=1', auth=HTTPBasicAuth('Authorization' : '563492ad6f91700001000001e4d5ce6a4c3986a01'))
```

Comment: Is that header really correct? This looks like a breach of RFCs [7235](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc7235) and [7236](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc7236). Anyhow, what you are attempting to do there is clearly not "basic" auth.

Comment: @DaSourcerer i'm trying to use this api https://www.pexels.com/api/ what exactly i'm doing wrong.

Comment: Probably nothing. Those who designed that API are not conforming to the relevant RFCs: The `Authorization` header requires a token identifying the [authentication scheme](http://www.iana.org/assignments/http-authschemes/http-authschemes.xhtml). Just tossing a token in there does not qualify.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think auth for this requires just a header with proper data, so I would try it like this:

```
requests.get("http://api.pexels.com/v1/search?query=people", headers={
    "Authorization": "563492ad6f91700001000001e4d5ce6a4c3986a01"
})
```

It corresponds exactly to the curl request with -H flag